# Is this proof that the vectors are colinear correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

I was solving the following exercise: "Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be nonzero such that if $z$ is orthogonal to $x$ then $z$ is orthogonal to $y$. Prove that $x$ and $y$ are colinear".

My idea was: since $x$ is nonzero, we know that we can write $y =\alpha x + z$ where $z$ is orthogonal to $x$. But, by hypothesis, being orthogonal to $x$ implies being orthogonal to $y$, so that taking the inner product on both sides with $z$ we have:

$$\left\langle y,z \right\rangle=\alpha\left\langle x,z \right\rangle + \left\langle z,z \right\rangle = 0,$$

but since $\left\langle x,z\right\rangle = 0$ this implies $|z|^2 = 0$ so that by properties of norm, we must have $z = 0$ proving that $y = \alpha x$.

Is this proof ok? I felt it was too easy to prove it and the answer in the book is a little different, so I thought there might be some error in this thought.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: What book are you looking at? I haven't seen it stated as a theorem before that $$y = \alpha x + z \text{ for } z \perp x,$$ but I see why it is true, and I like that way of putting it. Kind of like a Euclidean algorithm for vectors!

Comment: It's a book by the Brazilian mathematician Elon Lages Lima called Análise Real Volume 2. It's about analysis over $\mathbb{R}^n$. I'm afraid there's not a version in english though. But he does this proof on the beginning of the book. He takes $\alpha = \left\langle x,y \right\rangle / \left\langle x,x\right\rangle$ and then he let $z = y - \alpha x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof looks good to me!

Incidentally, an easier way might be to note that $$\langle x \rangle ^{\perp} = \langle y \rangle ^{\perp} \Rightarrow \left( \langle x \rangle ^{\perp} \right)^\perp = \langle x \rangle = \left( \langle y \rangle ^{\perp} \right)^\perp =  \langle y \rangle, $$ where $\langle x \rangle$ is the subspace generated by $x$.  But some of these things might not have been proven in your book yet...